# Export Enabled and Disabled AD Users (in two different files) to CSV with Powershell

Tags: csv, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I need to get enabled and disabled users separately with these properties:

- Full Name
- DisplayName
- EmailAddress
- Description
- AccountStatus

But I have a problem in typing in the right properties when retrieving disabled users. Can you please check and correct the script below? Also, I need to retrieve the enabled users with the same properties.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |
    Select -Property Name,SamAccountName,EmailAddress |
    Export-Csv "C:\\DisabledADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Search-ADAccount` returns only a subset of the users' properties. Pipe the search results through `Get-ADUser` to get all properties and restrict the output via `Select-Object:

```
$props = 'Name', 'DisplayName', 'EmailAddress', 'Description', 'Enabled'

Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |
    Get-ADUser -Properties $props |
    Select $props |
    Export-Csv "C:\\DisabledADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Beware that there are no properties/attributes "Full Name" or "AccountStatus". If you want custom properties you have to create them yourself as [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

```
Search-ADAccount –AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Name,DisplayName,EmailAddress,Description,Enabled |
    Select-Object @{n='Full Name';e={$_.Name}},
        DisplayName, EmailAddress, Description,
        @{n='AccountStatus';e={@('Disabled','Enabled')[([int]$_.Enabled)]}} |
    ...
```

However, since you want both enabled and disabled users (just in separate files), there's no point in enumerating them separately. Just call `Get-ADUser` and append the results to the respective file.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,DisplayName,EmailAddress,Description,Enabled |
    Select-Object @{n='Full Name';e={$_.Name}},
        DisplayName, EmailAddress, Description,
        @{n='AccountStatus';e={@('Disabled','Enabled')[([int]$_.Enabled)]}} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $csv = '{0}ADUsers.csv' -f $_.AccountStatus
        $_ | Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoType -Encoding UTF8
    }
```